# purescript halogen - render elements or nothing conditionally

Tags: purescript, purescript-halogen

I have a utility function to conditinally render elements:

```
thanRender :: ∀ w i. Boolean -> EL.HTML w i -> EL.HTML w i
thanRender true h = h
thanRender _    _ = EL.text ""
```

Usage:

```
isJust state.foo `thanRender` (EL.h1_ [ EL.text state.title ])
```

Is there a better way to "render nothing" as to render `EL.text ""` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Halogen doesn't allow maybe elements in `render`, the best way is as you have it returning `EL.text ""` to indicate no value. You can see it used in the [Real World Halogen example](https://github.com/thomashoneyman/purescript-halogen-realworld/blob/7acf8e30b4f32ba956a8162e7b33db1a353bf112/src/Component/HTML/Utils.purs#L31).

The other alternative if you're using child elements is to return an array, using a singleton array when the value is true and an empty array with the value is false:

```
thenRender :: forall w i. Boolean -> (Unit -> EL.HTML w i) -> Array (EL.HTML w i)
thenRender cond f = if cond then [ f unit ] else []

render _ =
  EL.div_
    $ (isJust state.foo `thenRender` \_ -> EL.h1 [ EL.text state.title ])
    <> renderOtherChildren
```

This doesn't work for the top-level render element since it needs to be a single element rather than an array of elements. Personally I think the first way you have it as is cleaner.